# XML data only show some of it

Tags: javascript, xml, titanium, tableview, titanium-mobile

So I am trying to get data from an XML file, but when i loop thru it and want to get out the "countyname" I only get the first one and then it stops. Is the XMl wrong? because I tried with other XML and that works fine with my code that gets the data into my tableview.
Best regards!
Filip

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<food_company>
<county>
    <countyname>New York</countyname>
    <city>
    <cityname>New York City</cityname>
        <restaurant>
            <name>Dinos pizzeria</name>
            <phone>01111111</phone>
            <location>broadway1</location>
        </restaurant>
        <restaurant>
            <name>Dinos pizzeria2</name>
            <phone>01111111</phone>
            <location>broadway2</location>
        </restaurant>
        <restaurant>
            <name>Dinos pizzeria3</name>
            <phone>01111111</phone>
            <location>broadway3</location>
        </restaurant>
    </city>
      <countyname>Baldwin County</countyname>
    <city>
    <cityname>Bay Minette</cityname>
        <restaurant>
            <name>Dinos pizzeria</name>
            <phone>01111111</phone>
            <location>broadway1</location>
        </restaurant>
        <restaurant>
            <name>Dinos pizzeria2</name>
            <phone>01111111</phone>
            <location>broadway2</location>
        </restaurant>
        <restaurant>
            <name>Dinos pizzeria3</name>
            <phone>01111111</phone>
            <location>broadway3</location>
        </restaurant>
    </city>
</lan>
</food_company>
```

app.js Code:

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#E1E6EE');



// create base UI tab and root window
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  


statusBarStyle: Ti.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.LIGHT_CONTENT,
tintColor: '#FFF',
backgroundColor:'#E1E6EE',
url: 'lan.js',
tabBarHidden: true,
navBarHidden: true
});

win1.open();
```

county.js Code:

```
Ti.include('app_functions.js');

var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

// create a table to display news feeds--------------------------------
var itemsTable = Ti.UI.createTableView({
top : '11%',
left : 0,
leftImage : 'taxi.png',
backgroundColor : '#DCEEDC', //E1E6EE
bottom : '0%',
// search : searchBar,
filterAttribute : 'searchFilter'
});
win.add(itemsTable);

// define xmlFeed (you can customize this with any RSS feed)
var xmlFeed = 'http://eventverket.nu/test/test5.xml';
//'http://83.254.164.137:1000/test.xml';

// create a new HTTP client object
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();

// this method will process the remote data
xhr.onload = function() {

// create an xml object
var xml = this.responseXML;

// create an array that will store news items for our tableView
var data = [];
var data = [];
var items = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("county");
for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    title: items.item(i).getTextContent()
}); 
data.push(row); 
}
itemsTable.data = data;

// when the user clicks on a row
itemsTable.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

// NEW WINDOW
var newWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : '#DCEEDC', //E1E6EE
    statusBarStyle : Ti.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.LIGHT_CONTENT,
    font : fonts[16]['normal'],
    url : "stad.js",
    //backButtonTitle: 'Back',
    //title: e.source.title,
    tabBarHidden : true,
    navBarHidden : true,
    tintColor : '#FFF'
    });

    newWindow.open();
   });

};

// this method will be called if there is an error in accessing the     data
xhr.onerror = function() {
    // hide activity indicator
activityIndicator.hide();

// display error
alert(this.status + ': ' + this.statusText);
return false;
};

// open the remote feed
xhr.open('GET', xmlFeed);

// execute the call to the remote feed
xhr.send();
```

city.js Code:

```
Ti.include('app_functions.js');

var newWin = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;



// create a table to display news feeds--------------------------------
var itemsTable = Ti.UI.createTableView({
top : '11%',
left : 0,
leftImage : 'taxi.png',
backgroundColor : '#DCEEDC', //E1E6EE
bottom : '0%',
// search : searchBar,
filterAttribute : 'searchFilter'
});
win.add(itemsTable);

// define xmlFeed (you can customize this with any RSS feed)
var xmlFeed = 'http://eventverket.nu/test/test5.xml';
//'http://83.254.164.137:1000/test.xml';

// create a new HTTP client object
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();

// this method will process the remote data
xhr.onload = function() {

// create an xml object
var xml = this.responseXML;

// create an array that will store news items for our tableView

var data = [];



var items = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("city");
for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    title: items.item(i).getTextContent() //
}); 
data.push(row); 
}
itemsTable.data = data;





// when the user clicks on a row
itemsTable.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

// NEW WINDOW
var newWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : '#DCEEDC', //E1E6EE
    statusBarStyle : Ti.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.LIGHT_CONTENT,
    font : fonts[16]['normal'],
    url : "stad.js",
    //backButtonTitle: 'Back',
    //title: e.source.title,
    tabBarHidden : true,
    navBarHidden : true,
    tintColor : '#FFF'
    });


 });

};

// this method will be called if there is an error in accessing the data
xhr.onerror = function() {
// hide activity indicator
activityIndicator.hide();

// display error
alert(this.status + ': ' + this.statusText);
return false;
};

// open the remote feed
xhr.open('GET', xmlFeed);

// execute the call to the remote feed
xhr.send();
```

Comment: _Do you think this question is answerable without knowing your code?_ **NO**.
Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Hi Michael!
I am so sorry, I did not think it thru!
Here comes my code: http://pastie.org/10397882

Here is how i get the XML data:
 
 `var items = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("county");`

 `// loop through each item`
 `for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {`

  `// create a table row for each item`
  `var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
   color : blackFontColor,
   title : items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("countyname").item(0).textContent,`

  `});`

Comment: I tried to edit it in your question, please correct it if it's wrong. Please allways include your code in your question whenever you ask one. This will help you to get an answer

Comment: Also, don't use `documentElement.getElementsByTagName("county")` for parsing xml. There are plenty of xml parsers on npm that might help you, e.g. have a look at https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

Comment: Thank for taking the time @michael!
Im not sure i can see what you changed, can you write it again? And i will definitely take a look at that github link :)

Comment: @michael , oh now i got it! thanks for putting in the code!

Comment: @michael Can you please check my new post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425511/xml-data-into-tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your code is wrong. Let me explain why... I'm going to comment your code and at the end you will understand what is wrong with it.

```
var items = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("county");
```

With this line of code you're getting all "county" elements of the XML file. In your case there is only one element. So `items` is a `Node.List` which contains just one element.

```
for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    ... 
}
```

With the `for` statement you're iterating through all the elements in `items`. In other words the content of the `for` statement will be repeated `items.lenght` times. But `items` contains only one element! So there will be no iterations.

Within your statement you're creating new rows. But only one row is going to be created, because of the fact that there are no itertions. For this reason you get only the first "countyname" tag.

I hope you've understood your error... Now i give to you a **simple solution** for your problem:

```
var data = [];
var items = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("countyname");
for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        title: items.item(i).getTextContent()
    }); 
    data.push(row); 
}
itemsTable.data = data;
```

My code just get a list of all the elements whose tag name is "countyname". According to your XML file `items` will be a `Node.List` with two elements. Then with a `for` statement it's possible to create new rows from the textContent of every node of the list!

Comment: Thank you so much @Riccardo Bucco !
This worked greate! 
But I have one question left! when i Press on the "New York" I just want the `<cityname>New York City</cityname>` to show up, but now both of the cityname shows up, is there a way to do this? Best regards Filip

Comment: You're welcome! But please show us your code: it is not possible to help you without it! I don't know how you're trying to implement it. Since the current problem has been solved, mark my answer as ACCEPTED. Then open another question with details about the other problem: remember to give us as many details as you can, so that it's possible to help you (and show us what you have already done!!)

Comment: Hi again @Riccardo Bucco !
Now I added all my code!
What I want to do is: get all the countys, and then press a county and get all the citys in that county. I can not press the "up arrow" because I do not have 15 points :/
Best regards. Filip

Comment: Riccardo Bucco 
check my new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425511/xml-data-into-tableview

Answer (score -1):

Check the xml,

Started with

```
<food_company>
   <county>
```

Ended with

```
   </lan>
</food_company>
```

Comment: Hi @roy!
Sorry thats my mistake! I translated it from swedish, and just forgot about to translate "lan"(county) to english for stackoverflow question

Comment: I could not comment on his post, I thought it may helped him... So posted here